# How to Extend a Morphism to a Quasiprojective Variety？

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a field and $\phi: k^*\rightarrow X$ be a morphism to a variety $X$.

My questions are:

1.When $X$ quasiprojective, why $\phi$ can be extended to $\bar\phi:\mathbb P^1\rightarrow \overline X$ where $\overline X$ is the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb P^n$?

2.Why $\overline{\phi(k^*)}-\phi(k^*)$ must be equal to $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\phi(x)$ or $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)$? (I'm also not really sure where do we take the closure for $\phi(k^*)$. in $X$ or in $\mathbb P^n$?)

3.Why $\phi$ is proper if and only if these limits do not exist in $X$?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think there might be a generalization. Let $X$ be scheme and $Y$ be quasiprojective scheme $\phi: U\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism from a dense open set. Then $\phi$ can be extended to $\overline{\phi}:X\rightarrow \overline Y$. Is this statement true? If it is true, is the extension unique or does that depend on the immersion $Y\subseteq \mathbb P^n$?

Comment: The first question is addressed in variety-theoretic language [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683395/), and in scheme-theoretic language [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593733/). The generalization in your comment is false, should probably be edited in to your question if you're interested in an answer, and has been addressed on this site before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312804/). You may find it helpful to do a bit more searching on your own next time.